# Where can I buy a camera off the internet?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, online-shopping

Can you list some of the trusted websites for buying cameras and lenses that deliver inside USA?

I am looking to buy a camera, and have heard that you can get some very good package deals (camera + lens + memory card, etc) off some of these sites. Unfortunately I dont know about any of these sites.

What are some such reputed sites?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few good options for buying new gear:

- http://www.Adorama.com
- http://www.bhphotovideo.com
- http://www.amazon.com

My personal favorite is Adorama, the service has always been wonderful.

Comment: All of these are quite reputable. My own preference is B&H for new gear.

Comment: Amazon is great if you're looking for a specific product or model, especially if you're a student and get free Amazon Prime. However, if you want to browse, Adorama and B+H are your better options.

Comment: @EvanKrall I agree, also, adorama and b+h both tend to have nice package deals.

Comment: Note that quite often, when buying off of Amazon, they are actually just fronting for Adorama or B&H anyway, so most of the time, your really just buying from those two. Excellent online stores, both!

Answer (score 7):

For used gear, **[KEH](http://keh.com)** is well-regarded. I find their prices not too much higher than individual sellers, they grade condition consistently and conservatively, and you get an inspection period and a short warranty.

Answer (score 3):

Another for used is [fredmiranda](http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/board/10) but you are buying of users, rather than the actual site.

Answer (score 3):

While I haven't used them for a camera or lenses (though they sell those too), [Midwest Photo Exchange](http://www.mpex.com/) is a great place for camera lighting & accessories.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised no one mentioned http://www.calumetphoto.com/. I tend to shop either there, at B&H, or at KEH.