# Best websites to find deals on purchasing Digital Camera / Equipment?

Tags: online-shopping

What are the best websites ( other than Amazon ) to find deals on purchasing digital cameras and equipment?. Canon EOS 60 D is on my wishlist and I am looking for Discount / Deals.

Most of my shopping cart is filled from Amazon.com, Is there any specific website where we can purchase only cameras and accessories?

Comment: You might want to add information about which country / region you're interested in. Europe? USA/Canada? Where?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I buy a camera off the internet?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3712/where-can-i-buy-a-camera-off-the-internet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've purchased equipment from following site with great satisfaction:

[bhphoto.com](http://bhphoto.com)
[adorama.com](http://adorama.com)
[keh.com](http://keh.com)

Answer (score 3):

Since you specifically say you're looking for discounts and deals -- and not the best shopping experience -- I recommend you check out a seller's listing on [Reseller Ratings](http://www.resellerratings.com/) and/or the [Better Business Bureau](http://www.bbb.org/). There seems to be a disproportional number of shady dealers for camera gear and electronics. Often the deals they offer are simply too good to be true -- because they are too good to be true!

Comment: I checked the links, Thank you !! Reseller Ratings site is good. But i am very much comfortable with @Allen suggestions !!

Answer (score 0):

New or used?

If you are in the US or Canada then I don't think you can beat **[B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/)** for **new equipment.** Ground shipping is often free. In Canada, it's so much cheaper then the cheapest Canadian equipment distributor that it is worth it to have have things shipped to your door and pay for the crazy brokerage prices and the tax.  I am lucky enough to live close the border so I have items shipped to a border store on the US side then drive down, pick it up and only pay the tax when crossing to Canada. 
I bought things from Adorama as well but I find B&H slightly cheaper and the service is amazing.

For **used items** you could use eBay or some of the ebay offshoots.  [**Kijiji**](http://toronto.kijiji.ca/) (owned by eBay) is very popular in Canada. It's a nation wide classified adds service that is very easy to use and defaults to local adds. I sold all of my old camera equipment (and 2 cars) on Kijiji and purchased some as well although I only buy brand new equipment when it comes to cameras and lenses.

Comment: Thank you !! I am voting as bhphoto.com and adorama.com  are the best sites to look around for Camera & its accessories !!

Answer (score 0):

B+H, as others have said, is a great place to buy camera gear. They do not do "deals" as much as have good everyday prices and excellent service. I've found that their prices always beat the Amazon prices. I've used them many times and have always been impressed.

I've also had good experiences at adorama and mpex.com

Comment: I agree with you @Pat Farrell, i like adorama !!

Answer (score 0):

For Canon equipment, it's worth keeping an eye on http://canonrumors.com and http://canonwatch.com. They often have eBay deals on Canon gear. These items are often gray market and therefore do not come with a US warranty, but the savings can sometimes be significant.

Comment: Also, just a note, but I've seen discounts of up to $1000 on high-end gear (5D Mark III and 1DX, mostly), and I'd gladly trade the warranty for that much of a discount. These extreme deals are fairly rare though.

Answer (score 0):

For Canon gear in the USA, if you don't like the inherent risks in purchasing used gear, another site to consider is [the refurbished products store on the Canon USA website](http://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/refurbished-products-information) itself.  While prices may be higher they generally match other refurbished offers, and you do get a 1-year Canon factory warranty on most products.